# Examples/documentation for the GeneticOptimizer in NumericalMethods library

Tags: c#, genetic-algorithm, numerical-methods

I'm looking for some examples of the usage of the GeneticOptimizer class in the NumericalMethods C# library from http://numerical.codeplex.com/

Specifically, what classes need to be subclassed, and what needs to be implemented.

It looks like this might have been a port from a Java library, if so, does anyone know what it is and if there exists any relevant documentation that might help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this is ported from the Java examples in ["Object-Oriented Implementation of Numerical Methods: An Introduction With Java and Smalltalk" by Didier H. Besset.](http://books.google.com/books/about/Object_oriented_implementation_of_numeri.html?id=kKfY0SB0O-cC&redir_esc=y)

Google Books seems to be missing the relevant pages so I've ordered a copy and will have to wait...